# How is it that $0\times\cos(\theta-\arctan{i})=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$??

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers, solution-verification, fake-proofs

We begin by assuming that $\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$ can be expressed in the form $R\cos(\theta-\alpha)$:
$$\begin{align}
\cos\theta+i\sin\theta
=&R\cos(\theta-\alpha)\\
=&R\cos\theta\cos\alpha+R\sin\theta\sin\alpha\\
\end{align}$$
$$\implies R\cos\alpha=1,~~R\sin\alpha=i$$
$$\implies R=\sqrt{1+(i)^2}=\sqrt{1-1}=0$$
Also,
$$\tan\alpha=i\implies \alpha=\arctan{i}$$
So we finish with
$$0\times\cos(\theta-\arctan{i})=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$$
How can this be?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You just showed, by contradiction, that $\cos \theta + i \sin \theta$ cannot be expressed in the form $R\cos (\theta - \alpha)$.

Comment: @player3236 Ah, so my initial assumption must be false?

Comment: Yes. Out of curiosity, why did you assume that in the first place?

Comment: @player3236 I was just thinking about $\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$ and I wondered if it could be represented in the form I gave in my assumption, which led to my result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\cos\theta+i\sin\theta=R\cos(\theta-\alpha)$, you cannot assume that $R$ and $\alpha$ are real, unless $\sin\theta=0$. What you proved is that there do not exist $R$ and $\alpha$ such that $R\cos\alpha=1$ and $R\sin\alpha=i$, because this implies $R=0$.

Let's see whether we can find them so that $\cos\theta+i\sin\theta=R\cos(\theta-\alpha)$ holds *for every* $\theta$.

With $\theta=0$, we get $1=R\cos(-\alpha)$; with $\theta=\pi/2$, we get $i=R\sin\alpha$. OK, they don't exist, because this implies $R^2\cos^2\alpha+R^2\sin^2\alpha=1+i^2=0$, but then $R^2=0$. Indeed $\cos^2\alpha+\sin^2\alpha=1$ for every $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$.